# Not able to create a dataproc cluster with image version 2.0 404 HTTP response code 22 exit code see output in

Tags: dataproc

Failed to initialize node <>: Failed to create event log dir with 404 HTTP response code and 22 exit code See output in

in dataproc i am creating a cluster with gcloud command for image version 2.0 i am getting error failed to initialize the node

when i run this command from local
gcloud create cluster cluster name --subnet=mysubnet --serviceaccount=myserviceaccount --image-version=2.0 bucket=bucketname